# Bounding $x^TAx$ when A is not a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, upper-lower-bounds

If $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is a real and symmetric, then we know that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$\lambda_{\min} (A) \|x\|^2 \le x^T A x \le \lambda_{\max} (A) \|x\|^2$$

where $\lambda_{\max}$ and $\lambda_{\min}$ are the maximum and minimum eigenvalues of $A$, respectively.

However if matrix $A$ is real and non-symmetric, as answered in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32786/what-non-symmetric-matrices-satisfy-xtax0-forall-x-neq-0), we identify that

$$x^T A x = x^T \left( \frac{A+A^T}{2} \right) x$$

So, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have

$$\Re(\lambda_{\min} (A)) \|x\|^2 \le \hat{\lambda}_{\min} \|x\|^2 \le x^T A x \le \hat{\lambda}_{\max}  \|x\|^2 \le \Re(\lambda_{\max} (A))\|x\|^2$$

where $\hat{\lambda}_{\min}$ and $\hat{\lambda}_{\max}$ are, respectively, the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $\frac{A+A^T}{2}$.

Is there anything more we could say about this bound? Is it possible to tighten or simplify it somehow?

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 4):

If we write the singular value decomposition of $A$ as $A= U \Sigma V^T$ with orthogonal matrices $U,\ V^T$ and $\Sigma = diag(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n)$ where $\sigma_i$ denotes a singular value we can bound $x^TAx$ by the following
$$ ||x^T Ax|| = ||x^TU \Sigma V^Tx||=|| u^T \Sigma v||\leq ||u^T|| \max_i{|\sigma_i|}||v||=||x|| \max_i{|\sigma_i|}||x||=\max_i{|\sigma_i|} ||x||^2 $$
with $u=U^Tx$ and $v =V^Tx$ and the fact that $||U^Tx||=||x||$ for any orthogonal matrix $U^T$.

Comment: Thanks. Does the bounds using singular values fit somewhere inside the ones I have with eigenvalues? I do not see an easy way as we do not have normal matrices...

Comment: Sorry I dont quite understand your question. Are you searching for a relation like $\max \sigma < \max \lambda$ or $\max \sigma > \max \lambda$?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there was a connection between $Re(\lambda_{min})||x||^2 \le x^TAx \le Re(\lambda_{max})||x||^2$ and $\sigma_{min}||x||^2 \le x^TAx \le \sigma_{max}||x||^2$·

Comment: Oh I don't know aboth that, but you can go this way 
$$
\max\{\min |\sigma|, \min |\lambda|\}\leq |x^TAx|\leq
\min\{\max |\sigma|, \max |\lambda|\}
$$

Comment: @Bravo perhaps this could help ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127500/what-is-the-difference-between-singular-value-and-eigenvalue

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something wrong with your logic when you claim that $\text{Re}(\lambda_\min)\leq \hat{\lambda}_\min$ and $\hat{\lambda}_\max\leq\text{Re}(\lambda_\max)$, so I think the original bound is wrong. A counterexample is $$A=\pmatrix{2&2\\-2&4}, \quad\quad\tfrac{A+A^T}{2}=\pmatrix{2&0\\0&4}.$$ The first has eigenvalues $3 \pm i \sqrt{3}$, while the second has eigenvalues 2 and 4.